# Android Multi-Touch pointerIndex out of range

Tags: android, multi-touch

Code from this book: [Programming Android, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023005.do).
At first I touch the screen with two fingers - everything OK.
Then touch the screen with one finger - **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range**

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    int idx;
    int n;
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            idx = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
            tracks.add(event.getPointerId(idx));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            idx = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
            tracks.remove(event.getPointerId(idx));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            n = event.getHistorySize();
            for (Integer i : tracks) {
                idx = event.findPointerIndex(i.intValue());
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    addDot(
                            dots,
                            event.getHistoricalX(idx, j),
                            event.getHistoricalY(idx, j),
                            event.getHistoricalPressure(idx, j),
                            event.getHistoricalSize(idx, j)
                    );
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    for (Integer i: tracks){
        idx = event.findPointerIndex(i.intValue());
        addDot(
                dots,
                event.getX(idx),
                event.getY(idx),
                event.getPressure(idx),
                event.getSize(idx)
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method findPointerIndex() may return -1. From what I have experienced this will happen when you touch with 2 fingers (or more) and let go of the first pressed finger.
I think this is the cause of 'pointerIndex out of range' error - since -1 is not a valid index :-)

For ACTION_MOVE I would recommend using a loop with getPointerCount(), ie looping from 0 to getPointerCount() - 1.
Using this method you can get touch position with getX(finger) and getY(finger).
Where 'finger' is your loop count.
Using this method will not keep track of what ID your finger has, ie if you press with two fingers and let go the first finger (ID=0) then the second finger will continue to count as the first finger (which is now not pressed)

Hope this helps!
/Richard